# Wish a custom extension (.plx) to run like a .exe on Windows 8

Tags: perl

I find that I have to change .exe files to .plx (which are compiled Perl files, Activestate) in order to email them.  Yet when they run within the host program, Windows 8 asks to associate the .plx with a program.  I just want the .exe to run on Windows like any .exe, and the user will not have Perl available.

Comment: What do you mean by the "host program"?  You want the email recipient to be able to double-click the file and "just run it"?  Can't the email recipient will need to rename back to `*.exe`?  If I take a "real" EXE file and rename it to *.plx, Windows 8.1 seems to run it just fine, without any special association for that extension.  How are you generating the EXE/PLX?  I can't find any docs for compiling Perl into PLX.

Comment: Thanks jimtut and tjd for quick response.  This is my first stackoverflow question.  I am a programmer on UNIX and so don't know Windows all that well.  I believe I will have to send .plx's and have an install PowerShell script rename them to .exes.  To answer your questions: The host program invoking the executable is either Excel VBA "shell" command or another compiled perl script that runs an "exec" on the .exe.  I renamed one of my .exe's to .plx and double clicked it and "How do you want to open this type of file (plx)?" comes up, with list of programs, w/o Windows OS. Just chose .plx.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Use the correct `.exe` extension.

**Background**: Back in the Perl 4 days, the `.pl` extension was used to designate 'Perl Library'.  On *nix, an 'executable' script was generally given a name without an extension, the file was given a mode with some variant of `+x`, and the file started with a `#!<some path>/perl` line.  In order to deal with shells that didn't handle `#!` lines, perl was given the ability to examine starting bytes of the file it's given and relaunch it with the correct interpereter if the file contained the correct 'magic number' and path.  The ActiveState folks, wishing to make 'executable' perl files on windows associated the `.pl` extension with their perl.exe.
Along comes Perl 5 with modules bearing the `.pm` extension and the diminishing use of 'Perl Libraries'.  ActiveState added the `.pm` extension to the list associated with `perl.exe`.  Seeing the increasing misapplication of the `.pl` extension, some Perl luminary suggested that the appropriate extension for a Perl Executable on Windows might be `.plx`.  ActiveState adds another association to `perl.exe`.

**Answer**: When you rename your `.exe` file with the incorrect `.plx` extension and double click on it, it is handed off to `perl.exe`.  Perl notices that your file is not in fact perl, but a windows executable, and relaunches it as such.  Your victim\h\h\h\h\h\hcustomer does not have Perl installed to correct the error.  In the end, the file should really have a `.exe` extension.

**Addendum**: What `perlapp` does with a perl program is a 'compilation' in the same sense as "Queen's Greatest Hits".  It zips up a `.dll` version of `perl.exe`, the perl program and all it's required modules along with a nice little stub that unzips it all into a temp directory & runs it.  None of this changes the fact that this stub is still a Windows Executable at heart.

Comment: Thanks.  Will send a .plx and have an install script rename to .exe.  QUESTION:  Does what you say in the addendum mean that someone can just find that temp dir and see all the source ?

Comment: @MichaelFox, Yes it does.  Perlapp is a convenient packaging technique, but not a protection for your source code.  Because it is so easy to reverse engineer most source hiding techniques, the best protection you can give your source code, according to most experts, is the combination of a good License & a good lawyer.